# Using fold in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to learn smlnj at the moment and am having trouble with a fold function.

What I'm trying to do is write a function, select, that uses the folding pattern and takes in a function and a list.  It will take the head of the list into the function to determine whether it will add that element to the list.  Here is an example of what I mean.

```
          select (fn x => x mod 2 = 0) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
          val it = [2,4,6,8,10] : int list
```

So, here is what I have so far...

```
          fun select f l = foldl (fn (x,y) => if (f(x)) then x else 0) 0 l;
```

This obviously doesn't work correctly.  It simply returns 10.  I'm sure I need to use op:: somehow to get this to work, but I can't figure it out.  My thought is that it should look something like this...

```
          fun select f l = foldl (fn (x,y) => if (f(x)) then op:: else []) [] l;
```

But this does not work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. The only problems are the `if`/`else` cases in the function you're passing to `fold`.

Remember, in your `fn (x,y)`, `x` is the list element you're considering, and `y` is the result of folding the rest of the list. If `f(x)` fails, then you want to exclude `x` from the result, so you just pass `y` along. If `f(x)` succeeds, you want to include `x` in your result, so you return `y@[x]`.

Note that it's best to avoid using the append operator (`y@[x]`) where you can, as it's a linear-time operation, while prepending (`x::y`) is constant. Of course, substituting one for the other in this case will construct your list backwards. You can get around this by folding backwards as well, i.e. using `foldr` instead of `foldl`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're implementing already exists. It's called `filter`.

```
- List.filter (fn x => x mod 2 = 0) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
val it = [2,4,6,8,10] : int list
```

Your attempt in your second code sample is pretty close. There are several issues I might point out:

- `op::` is an operator, which is a function. You probably don't want to return a function. Instead, you probably want to use the operator to create a list from a head element and the rest of the list, like this: `x :: y`
- In the else case, you are currently returning an empty list, and throwing away whatever was accumulated in `y`. You probably don't want to do that.
- Think about whether left-fold or right-fold would be most suitable for your output

Comment: Thank you.  I really appreciate your advice.